# DB2 or DashDB services in Bluemix

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

We are trying to find out DB2 or Dash DB in Bluemix as a service, but we couldn't find it. 
1. Is this Service removed from Bluemix.
2. Our existing apps using Dashdb will continue to run without any issue. 
3. Please let us know how to get DasdDB and Elastic Search in Bluemix as service.
Thanks.
Gurunath.

Answer (score 0):

**Db2 Warehouse on Cloud** is the former **dashDB** service and **Db2 on Cloud** is the former **dashDB for Transactions** service. You can find both in the [database category of the IBM Cloud Catalog](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog?category=databases).

When you look at this [unofficial site](https://mycatalog.mybluemix.net/) and click on the related command icon, you will notice that the service name is still **dashDB**:

```
ibmcloud cf create-service dashdb Flex <service-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they (db2 team) preferred provisioning it from public cloud. We also using db2 for our apps and it works fine. My only concern is, scaling up my resources, but I think that would be also not a problem.